# Инициализация вектора в структуре

Tags: c++

Есть такая структура:

```
typedef unsigned char byte;
struct A
{
    int a;
    byte b;
    std::vector<int>z;
}
```

Хочу написать метод для инициализации нулём полей структуры.

```
void setZero()
{
    memset(this,0,sizeof(A));
}
```

Вот только с вектором проблема. Нельзя так делать. А как можно, не понимаю.

Comment: Вектор не надо инициализировать, он по умолчанию и так пустой. А для класса напишите подходящий конструктор и все дела.

Comment: Поля класса можно инициализировать и напрямую в определении: **int a = 0;**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно просто добавить конструктор, в котором все поля занулить. Вектор занулять никак не нужно, т.к. он по умолчанию пустой и готовый к работе.

```
A::A() : a(0), b(0) {}
```

Если конструктор не приемлем, если нужно именно внешней функцией занулить, тогда просто нужно занулить каждое примитивное поле:

```
void Zeroize(A & a) {
    a.a = 0;
    a.b = 0;
}
```

Также в C++11 можно писать инициализацию полей прямо в структуре.

```
struct A {
    int a = 0;
    byte b = 0;
    std::vector<int> z;
};
```

По поводу `memset()`, таким методом можно занулять структуры, у которых все поля примитивные (числа, Си массивы). Если хоть одно поле представляет сложный класс, например *STL* класс, тогда занулять всё нельзя. В этом случае через `memset` можно занулять отдельные члены, которые примитивные.

Comment: "в новом C++11" ... уже с++17 утверждён :)

Comment: @alexolut Новый относительно классического исходного С++. Т.к. не во всех местах даже C++11 поддерживается. Например в Microchip PIC внедрённых процессорах (я для них пишу) поддерживается начальный С++, но не С++11.

Comment: *Во всех местах* никогда не будет поддерживаться. Просто это места старые, а не C++ новый.